# A doubt about Cauchy's theorem in group theory.

Tags: group-theory

I am reading Cauchy's theorem in Group Theory,which states that if $p$ divides $|G|$, where $p$ is a prime number, then $a\in G$ such that $a\neq 1$ and $a^p=1$.

On reading the proof, it seems clear to me that the number of such elements is a multiple of $p$.

The argument:

> Let $X$ be the set of all $p$-tuples in $G$ such that $a_1a_2\dots a_p=1$.
>
> Let $X_\sigma$ be the subset of $X$ such that every cyclic permutation of every element in the set is equal to the original element. An example would be $\underbrace{(a,a,a,\dots,a)}_{\text{p times}}$. It is clear that every element of $X_\sigma$ would be of this form only, in which all the $p$ elements in the $p$-tuple will be the same.
>
> The proof then goes on to prove that $p$ divides $|X_\sigma|$. Also, $|X_\sigma|$ is non-empty as $(1,1,\dots,1)\in X_\sigma$. Hence $|X_\sigma|$ is a multiple of $p$.

Am I reading the proof wrong? If there are indeed $rp$ elements of order $p$ in $G$, where $r$ is some natural number, why would Cauchy state something much weaker; that there is at least one such element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is very unclear what you're confused about.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Note that if $G$ contains an element $x$ of order $p$ then it contains the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup, namely $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{p-1}\}$ and each element in this subgroup has order $p$.  So the statement "$G$ has an element of order $p$" is equivalent to - not weaker than - the statement "The number of elements of order $p$ in $G$ is a positive multiple of $p$".

Comment: Well, I guess $1$ does not have order $p$, but my point remains.

Answer (score 0):

The number of such elements is *not* a multiple of $p$. Consider $\mathbb{Z}_p$. You are counting the identity as well, which has order $1$.

Secondly, if you have one element of order $p$, you can generate $p-2$ more by its powers. It must generate a subgroup of order $p$, and those elements (other than the identity) have order $p$.

Comment: Fine, doing away with the identity, can I say there are at least $p-1$ such elements?

Comment: Yep! But you only need one to recover the others.